# CSS disappear after I set my django project into the cloud server

Tags: django

Site administration
Authentication and Authorization Groups     Add     Change
Users   Add     Change
Dataloginin Loginin_ tables     Add     Change
Recent actions
My actions

None available

become like this.

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate more on problem you are facing.
My best guess is that it can be solved using collectstatic command.
`python manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: thanks,the problem is coming from the setting...I solve it but I forget the method...I only remember the method is change a setting from false to true.